# How can I assign a name of this combobox(Name = Combobox1) and range it to a fixed position (Cell C4)?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1",Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, Height:=15)
    With .Object
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
    End With
End With
```

**How Can I assign a name and fix the position of it (based on the code above)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = Range("C4")

 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Rng.Left, Top:=Rng.Top, Width:=100, Height:=15)
   .Name = "Combobox_Name" ' change the name
    With .Object
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
    End With
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ComboBx1 As OLEObject

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ComboBx1 = ws.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")

With ComboBx1
        .Left = ws.Range("C4").Left
        .Top = ws.Range("C4").Top
        .Name = "WateverYouWant"
        .Width = "150"
End With

With ws.OLEObjects("WateverYouWant").Object
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried your method, but it doesn't work with my excel file....Did you try it?

Comment: in which line do you have the error? Do you use excel on mac?